# Does "play nice" mean "pretend to be nice"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

People say "**play innocent**" or "**play dead**" to mean "pretend to be innocent" or "pretend to be dead" respectively.

Can we apply that way of saying to the adjective "nice"?

Does "**play nice**" mean "**pretend to be nice**"?

Comment: No.  "to play nice" is an idiom. It means to behave without causing trouble.

Comment: There is no pretending in play nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Play nice' is an idiom. It means to not cause trouble; to play without arguing; share your toys.

It's a common expression for a parent to children who are squabbling.
As noted in comments - if this is said to adults, it often implies they are being childish.

I suppose strictly, it perhaps ought to be 'play nicely' but no-one ever really says that.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that, when said to adults, it often implies that they are being childish.

Comment: Had to remove my upvote when I got to your last sentence.  If no one ever says it, then the "strict" rule was made up, by a bozo.

Comment: @TimR - Seems an odd reason to remove the vote… like "Think Different". Americans didn't mind it, it drove Brits bananas. It should be an adverb, but no-one ever does it correct. :P

Comment: Adverbing weirds language.

Comment: @ColinFine - ermmm… whut?? I know each of those words, but they don't seem to add up to anything meaningful.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.  I thought you were doing well up to that point. The rap-your-knuckles-with-a-ruler kind of grammar primers that insisted on adverbs in expressions where no native speaker "in the wild" would ever use one simply did not recognize how the language actually worked and were trying to make it be something that it wasn't.

Comment: @TimR - this is just another of those US/UK differences. They US doesn't mind dropping the adverb & will do it happily & frequently. Brits hate it. Please don't ever claim 'no native speaker' does something or other, because the US is not the only native speaker of English.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Well, you're the one who said "but no-one ever really says that". I agreed with that. And it's not an AmE/BrE distinction.

Comment: @TimR - shall I get my knife & fork out? You do seem to be making rather a meal of this tiny afterthought of a distinction. Really, is this the hill to pick to die on?

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I'm not trying to pick a fight, just pointing out that in your final sentence there is a reflection of a view of grammar that is known as "prescriptive" grammar, which sets arbitrary rules based on an ideal the pedagogue would like the language to live up to, as distinct from *descriptive* grammar that seeks to describe the rules that govern the language as it is actually spoken (and written) by competent native speakers, acknowledging dialect differences.

Comment: There is a not insignificant minority who will correctly use the adverb - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=play+nice%2C+play+nicely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 Please pick another hill, I'm rapidly tiring of this one.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25

Comment: @DoneWithThis. "Correctly"?